# How to modify Matlab Script in python to call data

Tags: python, matlab

my data file is like this in .mat:
[data_input_file][1] .
First column: year; Second column: days; Third column: data

Initially, I wrote a code in Matlab to pick the data (CF) in a sliding window fashion (-5, +5) days and then stacks the values in variables. Matlab script is

```
bpn=1
 for i = 1:lengday % for i in range(lengday)
        zz2 = 0;
        zz=0;
        for j = -5:5  % days to be stacked
            k=i+j;
            if k > lengday; k = lengday; end
            if k <1; k = 1; end
            zz =CFdata(k).NCF(1:end,bpn)'./max(CFdata(k).NCF(1:end,bpn))/(abs(j)+1);
            zz2= zz2+zz;
  end
```

I was required to transform my script to python. However, the last line of the script is not working: Here is my attempted, these variables are defined in below

```
mat=scipy.io.loadmat('hydhyd_1.mat') #read the mat file


day=CFdata["day"]
firstday=1
lastday=len(day[0])
total_day=np.arange(firstday,lastday)

for i in range(lastday):
    zz2 = 0;
    zz=0;
    for j in range(-5,5):
        k=i+j;
       # print(k)
        if k > lastday:
            k = lastday
        if k <1:
            k = 1
  #  print(k)
zz2=0
#zz =mat['CFdata'][k]['NCF'][0:lastday,1]/max([mat['CFdata']['NCF'][0:lastday,1]])/[abs(j)+1]; #this is not working
zz =CFdata['NCF'][0,0:9]/max([mat['CFdata']['NCF'][0:lastday,1]])/[abs(j)+1];
zz2= zz2+zz
plt.plot(zz[0])
```

**Function of the above line:**
This line selects a specific day, then takes the data of plus/minus 5 days (around the selected day). Afterward, stack the data of all 11 days.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3kKX.png

Comment: It’s impossible to tell what you’re doing in the Python code, please post more of it for context. All I can tell is that there’s no `k` in that line. Your MATLAB code doesn’t fit your description of it, I presume it’s been cut down? Please read [mre].

Comment: Sorry for that, when I added the K in Python, it did not work. I cut the code because i suppose that it would be a bit long. I will modify my question. Thanks for the comment.